# wget directory-prefix not working, downloads to ftp host directory

Tags: linux, wget

I'm trying to use wget to download from a ftp host and download the files to a specified directory but this does not work. It instead downloads to a directory that has the same name as the ftp host. I used the -P and --directory-prefix option but with no success; I used : after the host and double slashes nothing works;

Examples that do not work, and download to a directory with the name of the ftp host:

wget -r -N -P /my/path/ ftp : //user:pass@ftphost/copydir/*

wget -r -N -P /my/path/ ftp :  //user:pass@ftphost//copydir/*

wget -r -N -P /my/path/ ftp : //user:pass@ftphost:copydir/*

wget -r -N -directory-prefix=/my/path/ ftp : //user:pass@ftphost/copydir/*

wget -r -N -directory-prefix=/my/path/ ftp : //user:pass@ftphost//copydir/*

wget -r -N -directory-prefix=/my/path/ ftp : //user:pass@ftphost:copydir/*

they all download in a directory called ftphost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` defaults to create per-host directories when used in recursive mode. To disable you need to specify the [`--no-host-directories`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Directory-Options) (`-nH`) option.